# Proving the unicity of $r$ where $r^n = x$ (with $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ge 0$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge 1$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}, r \ge 0$).

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For some reason I'm not convinced of my proof of the unicity of $r$ in the following statement:

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ge 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 1$. Then there is only one number $r \in \mathbb{R}, r \ge 0$ such that $r^n = x$.

**Here is what I've done so far:**

Let's assume that there is another number $z \in \mathbb{R}, z \ge 0$ such that $z \ne r$ and $z^n = x$.

Therefore, $z^n = x = r^n$ and $z^n-r^n = 0$.

We know that $z^n - r^n = (z-r) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^{k} z^{n-1-k}$. Since $z-r \ne 0$ (because $z \ne r$ by assumption), we're supposed to find that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^{k} z^{n-1-k} = 0$ leads to a contradiction.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^{k} z^{n-1-k} = r^0 z^{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} r^{k} z^{n-1-k} + r^{n-1} z^0$

Now, let's consider a special case: if $z=0$, then $r > 0$ and if we assume that $0^0 = 1$, we have a contradiction since this we get that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^{k} z^{n-1-k} = r^{n-1} \ne 0$.

If $z, r > 0$, then we get a contradiction as well since $n \ge 1$ and $r, z > 0$ implies that all the terms of our sum are positive numbers. Therefore, we can't have a sum equal to $0$.

**My problems are the following:**

In the case of $z=0$, what if $0^0 = 0$? How can I convince myself that $0^0 = 1$ in that case?

Furthermore, what if $0 < r < 1$ and if $n$ is huge? We know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} q^n = 0$ when $|q| < 1$, so how can I be sure that, if $z=0$, then $r^{n-1} \ne 0$?

Comment: The formula doesnt have (to have) a $r^0z^{n-1}$, it has a $z^{n-1}$.

Comment: In your statement, $n\geq 1$. Why do you have a question about $0^0$?

Comment: @Jack Because the formula $z^n - r^n = (z-r) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k z^{n-1-k}$ implies the apparition of $r^0 z^{n-1}$ and $r^{n-1} z^0$, and I don't really see why $n \ge 1$ is supposed to solve that problem...

Comment: @Hellen I don't get your point... Sorry for being a little bit dumb :(

Comment: The formula is written that way to be compact or to aid the memory. It is really $z^n-r^n=(z-r)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-1}r+z^{n-2}r^2+...+r^{n-1})$, defined for all $r,z$. No need to use the function $z^0$ or $r^0$.

Comment: @Hellen Ok, thanks for the answer. But it still doesn't help for my second question ; do you have any idea about that? That would be great :)

Comment: There is no limit in the problem, all numbers are fixed no matter how large or small. An extremely small non-zero number is still non-zero (tautologically).

Comment: No. No problem. For all $n$ ($r\geq0$ and $r\neq0$) implies  $r^n\geq0$ and $r^n\neq0$. $r^n\geq0$ by multiplying the inequalities, and $r^n\neq0$ due to $\mathbb{R}$ being an integral domain.

Comment: @Jack Why did you delete your answer? It could still have been useful to me... :/

Comment: @Hellen Thanks for the help and for your time. I didn't know what an integral domain was, but now it makes more sense. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Google keeps catched versions of pages. You can still see the [version of the page with the answer before it was deleted](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7MiWxDzTMNcJ:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373752/proving-the-unicity-of-r-where-rn-x-with-x-in-mathbbr-x-ge-0-wi+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca).